# Лог действий с файлами

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Подскажите как реализовать программу которая будет вести лог действий с файлами (Открытия/закрытия/удаления). Хочу реализовать такой лог: 
`[06:01:2020] 1/1/file.txt [Открылся]`

Знаю что можно использовать хуки, но слаб в этой теме. Заранее спасибо!